# Split by semicolon of a string not working

Tags: apex, email, class, string, split

In below code semicolon separation not working for string with email addresses. Can someone help please?

**Apex code**

```
List<ABV_Form_Request_abv__c>  Useremails= ABV_Form_Request_abv__c.getAll().values();
        if(!Useremails.isEmpty()){
          system.debug('Useremails@@'+Useremails);
           for(ABV_Form_Request_abv__c Useremail : Useremails)
           {
               if(String.isnotBlank(Useremail.Email_abv__c)){
                   for(String estr : Useremail.Email_abv__c.split(';')){
                        if(string.isnotBlank(estr))
                            sendtoemail.add(estr);

..................................................
```

Comment: Can you add some input/output combos? Seems fine at first glance.

Comment: Put System.debug('Useremail.Email_abv__c ' + Useremail.Email_abv__c) before, after, and in your Ifs

Comment: Its a standard practice to separate emails with comma http://stackoverflow.com/a/12120203/1343065, are you sure its semicolon and not comma ?

Comment: If not careful, by using semicolons, you could easily be creating lists of strings instead of a single string of email addresses, esp if using brackets `[]` followed by `{}` curly braces notation (in source code for emails that is).

Comment: Can you maybe post an example string you are trying to split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely is not an issue with splitting the string, simplified the code a bit and ran the following in the execute anonymous window to demonstrate:

```
List<String>  Useremails = new List<String>{
    'first@second.com;second@first.com',
    'third@fourth.com;fourth@third.com',
    'fifth@sixth.com', 'six@seven.com'};
List<String> emailResults = new List<String>();

for(String Useremail : Useremails) {
    for(String email : Useremail.split(';')){
        emailResults.add(email);
        System.debug(email);
    }
}

System.debug(emailResults);
```

[image: debug results]